# Why error with installing csv when its part of python core package in scrapinghub

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub, zyte

I have 3 spiders defined.
All the related requirements are mentioned in requirements.txt

```
scrapy
pandas
pytest
requests
google-auth
functions-framework
shub
msgpack-python
```

Also, the scrapinghub.yml defined to use scrapy 2.5

```
project: ******
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
stacks:
  default: scrapy:2.5
```

And I keep getting this error when trying to deploy:

```
    Packing version 2d90036-master
Deploying to Scrapy Cloud project "*****"
Deploy log last 30 lines:

Deploy log location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\shub_deploy_78so4sa8.log
Error: Deploy failed: b'{"status": "error", "message": "Requirements error"}'
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.5
 ---> f80194ae2e0c
Step 2/3 : ADD kumo-entrypoint /kumo-entrypoint
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f2cacb9a9322
Step 3/3 : RUN chmod +x /kumo-entrypoint
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89678c9537bf
Successfully built 89678c9537bf
Successfully tagged kumo-entrypoint:latest
Entrypoint container is created successfully
>>> Checking python dependencies
Collecting pip<20.0,>=9.0.3
  Downloading pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
-main- 0.0.1 requires csv, which is not installed.
-main- 0.0.1 requires datetime, which is not installed.
-main- 0.0.1 requires logging, which is not installed.
-main- 0.0.1 requires re, which is not installed.
Warning: Pip checks failed, please fix the conflicts.
WARNING: There're some errors when doing pip-check:
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -main- (/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -main- (/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -main- (/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg)
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/app/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
{"message": "Dependencies check exit code: 1", "details": "Pip checks failed, please fix the conflicts", "error": "requirements_error"}
{"status": "error", "message": "Requirements error"}
```

Also the Setup.py

```
setup(
    name="scraper",
    version=VERSION,
    author="Something",
    author_email="<something@gmail.com>",
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    long_description=long_description,
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['csv', 'logging', 'datetime', 'scrapy', 'pandas', 'pytest'],
    keywords=['python', 'scrapy'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Developing",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: Unix",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
    ],
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = my_project_name.settings']}
)
```

> The Project ID is masked

Can you please help me understand why the following packages needs to be installed by scraping hub when these seems to be part of the core python package itself:

- csv
- datetime
- logging

Really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This line probably is the one of most interest: `botocore 1.20.62 has requirement urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4, but you have urllib3 1.22.`

Comment: Install a more recent version of urllib3 between versions 1.25.4 and less than 1.27, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't fix the issue. I am not getting the error for urllib anymore of course.

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` file?

Comment: Yes I do. and entrypoint is also defined on the same. Updated the question with the setup.py

Comment: you were correct, I had csv, datetime and logging dependencies on setup.py. Thats was what causing the error. Thank you for pointing out setup.py @Chris

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. It would be better to include the old `setup.py` in your question so the problem becomes clear and then add an answer. You can either to that yourself, or I'd be happy to write one if you update the question.

Comment: Yes Chris. Done the same. I have added the setup.py on the question and have highlighted the issue in the answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The error was on the setup.py. The requirements.txt had conflicts with the install_requires= in setup.py.